# Apache Calcite 1.13.0 produced null pointer exception compared to 1.12.0

Tags: java, csv, apache-calcite

Using Apache Calcite on Windows and trying to query the DEPTS.csv used on the website tutorial I get a NullPointerException when using Calcite Core 1.13.0 but when I use 1.12.0 the issue disappears.

```
Properties info = new Properties();
    info.put("model",  "../src/test/resources/files.json");
    info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

    String sql = "select * from FILES.DEPTS"; 
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
```

And the exception is as follows:-

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while executing SQL "select * from FILES.DEPTS": null

at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:156)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeQuery(AvaticaStatement.java:218)
at za.co.bb8.CalciteTests.testConnection(CalciteTests.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.validate(VolcanoPlanner.java:891)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.register(VolcanoPlanner.java:866)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.ensureRegistered(VolcanoPlanner.java:883)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.ensureRegistered(VolcanoPlanner.java:101)
at org.apache.calcite.rel.AbstractRelNode.onRegister(AbstractRelNode.java:336)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.registerImpl(VolcanoPlanner.java:1496)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.setRoot(VolcanoPlanner.java:308)
at org.apache.calcite.tools.Programs$5.run(Programs.java:309)
at org.apache.calcite.tools.Programs$SequenceProgram.run(Programs.java:387)
```

Comment: Sorry you haven't gotten a response sooner. I'd suggest you file an issue on our [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CALCITE) as it's easier to keep track of things that way. I'm not sure I'll be able to help, but I'm sure someone will be able to sort this out for you.

Comment: Logged in JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-1952